# Read/write operation works neither good nor bad

Tags: c++, visual-c++, buffer

I am programming a face detection algorithm. In my code I'm parsing an XML file (in a recursion way, very inefficient takes my about 4 minutes to parse the whole XML file). I'd like to save the XML content using **Iosteam** binary to a file. I'm using a struct in C++ in order to  use the raw data.

My goal is to parse the XML **only** if the raw data file is not exist.

The method work like this:

1. If the raw data file is not exist, parse the XML file and save the data to a file.
2. If the raw data file exist, read the raw data from the file

My problem is: whenever I open the raw data  file and read from it. I get to read only small amount of byte from the file, I don't know how much, but in a certain point I receive only 0x00 data on my buffer.

My guess: I believe this has to do with the OS buffer, Which has a certain amount of buffer for  read and write operations. I might be wrong about this. Though I'm not sure which one from the operations doesn't work well, it's either the write or read.

I was thinking to write / read the raw data char by char or line by line. In the other hand  the file doesn't contain a text, which means that I can't read line by line or char by char.

The raw data size is

```
   size_t datasize = DataSize();   ==  196876 (Byte)
```

Which is retrieve in this function

```
/* Get the upper bound for predefined cascade size  */
size_t CCacadeInterpreter::DataSize()           
{
// this is an upper boundary for the whole hidden cascade size
size_t datasize = sizeof(HaarClassifierCascade) * TOTAL_CASCADE+    
    sizeof(HaarStageClassifier)*TOTAL_STAGES +
    sizeof(HaarClassifier) * TOTAL_CLASSIFIERS  + 
    sizeof(void*)*(TOTAL_CASCADE+TOTAL_STAGES+TOTAL_CLASSIFIERS);   

return datasize;
 }
```

The method work like this

```
BYTE * CCacadeInterpreter::Interpreter()
 {
printf("|Phase - Load cascade from memory |  CCacadeInterpreter::Interpreter | \n"); 

size_t datasize = DataSize();
// Create a memory structure 
nextFreeSpace = pStartMemoryLocation = new BYTE [datasize];
memset(nextFreeSpace,0x00,datasize);

// Try to open a predefined cascade file on the current folder (instead of parsing the file        again)
fstream stream; 
stream.open(cascadeSavePath);  // ...try existing file          
if (stream.is_open())  
{
    stream.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    stream.read((char*)pStartMemoryLocation , datasize);  // **ream from file** 
    stream.close();
    printf("|Load cascade from saved memory location |  CCacadeInterpreter::Interpreter | \n"); 
    printf("Completed\n\n"); 
    stream.close();
    return pStartMemoryLocation; 
}

        // Open the cascade file and parse the cascade xml file 
std::fstream cascadeFile;
cascadeFile.open(cascadeDestanationPath, std::fstream::in);      // open the file with read only attributes 
if (!cascadeFile.is_open())
{
    printf("Error: couldn't open cascade XML file\n"); 
    delete pStartMemoryLocation; 
    return NULL;
}

// Read the file XML file , line by line
string buffer, str; 
getline(cascadeFile,str);
while(cascadeFile)
{
    buffer+=str; 
    getline(cascadeFile,str);
}
cascadeFile.close(); 
split(buffer, '<',m_tokens); 

// Parsing begins 
pHaarClassifierCascade = (HaarClassifierCascade*)nextFreeSpace; 
nextFreeSpace += sizeof(HaarClassifierCascade);
pHaarClassifierCascade->count=0;
pHaarClassifierCascade->orig_window_size_height=20;
pHaarClassifierCascade->orig_window_size_width=20;

m_deptInTree=0;
m_numOfStage = 0; 
m_numOfTotalClassifiers=0;
while (m_tokens.size())
{
    Parsing();
}
// Save the current cascade into a file 
SaveBlockToMemory(pStartMemoryLocation,datasize);
printf("\nCompleted\n\n"); 
return pStartMemoryLocation;
    }

   bool CCacadeInterpreter::SaveBlockToMemory(BYTE * pStartMemoryLocation,size_t dataSize)
   {
fstream stream; 
if (stream.is_open() )   
    stream.close();   

stream.open(cascadeSavePath);  // ...try existing file          
if (!stream.is_open())  // ...else, create new file...
    stream.open(cascadeSavePath, ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);

stream.seekg(0,ios::beg);
stream.write((char*)pStartMemoryLocation,dataSize);
stream.close(); 
return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/quick_reference.html) IOstreams library.
It has an easy to use wrrapers for file handling